# Does $x<y$ and $a\le b\implies x+a<y+b$? Similarly, does $x>y$ and $a\ge b\implies x+a>y+b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I know this is a very simple question, but I still have my doubts on this question:

> Does $x<y$ and $a\le b\implies x+a<y+b$? Similarly, does $x>y$ and $a\ge b\implies x+a>y+b$? Why or why not?

Based on intuition, these seem to be true, but how would I "prove" this concretely? I'm not too sure if there are any rules that allow me to combine $<$ and $\le$(or $>$ and $\ge$) inequalities. It seems like there should be one, but I wasn't able to find any. Could someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

If $x<y$, then $x+a<y+a$ and then, if $a\leqslant b$, $y+a\leqslant y+b$, and therefore $x+a<y+b$.

Answer (score 1):

You can always add two inequalities in the the same direction: $P>Q$ and $R>S$
means $P+R >Q+S$. But you cannot subtract two inequalities in the same direction (sometime you may get right rsult and sometime wrong, so one avoids their subtraction). You are right in both the cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you always remember this in your head: $x<y \iff x-y<0; a \le b \iff a-b \le 0$.

Then $(x+a)-(y+b) = (x-y)+(a-b) <0 \implies x+a<y+b.$

The other direction is similar.